# model_viewer_plus model pan enabled

Tags: flutter, dart, 3d-model

I'm looking to add a pan to a 3d model.

I have a map and you can zoom into the map but there is no pan. is there any way to add this?

https://pub.dev/packages/model_viewer_plus/score

```
ModelViewer(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xEE),
        src: 'assets/map/ComplexMap.glb', // a bundled asset file
        alt: "Test",
        ar: false,
        autoRotate: false,
        cameraControls: true,
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter does provide a widget that allows for panning and zooming of a child widget. This widget is called `InteractiveViwer`.

To use this widget you will need to wrap the `ModelViewer` Widget within an `InteractiveViewer` like below

```dart
InteractiveViewr(
    child: ModelViewer(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(0xFF, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xEE),
        src: 'assets/map/ComplexMap.glb', // a bundled asset file
        alt: "Test",
        ar: false,
        autoRotate: false,
        cameraControls: true,
      );
)
```

---

**Docs**

[InteractiveViewer Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html)

Comment: So I did have this originally but because of the 3d viewer takes up the entire screen so the interactive viewer doesn’t actually pan if you are still trying to use the camera on the model viewer to rotate the model

Answer (score 0):

Hey if someone's still stuck, they can try setting the `enablePan:true` for example:

```
ModelViewer(
  src: '...',
  alt: 'alt text',
  ar: true,
  autoRotate: true,
  cameraControls: true,
  enablePan: true,
),
```

This allows two finger touch dragging around. Worked for me.